# Why DTOs are not generally not maintained in spring container?

Tags: spring, frameworks, dto

Why DTOs are not generally not maintained in spring container ? If we maintained in spring container ,what are the advantages and disadvantages related to it? can we achieved using prototype scope for these DTOs ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use spring to produce DTO's with a factory method. Doing this may be a matter of taste vs. just creating the object directly with `new`. If you want to be a purist in your use of DI, I suppose you can use a factory, but generally speaking, a DTO would not have any dependencies so the benefit of injection isn't really there.

One very useful idiom with DTO's is the use of a `builder`. This allows you to handle optional properties quite elegantly as well as enforce invariants. For more information, check out Bloch's rather definitive [post](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2) on the subject.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Bloch's post.

Comment: Thanks leeor for your answer. If we use Spring DI , is there any issue like any chance of loosing state of an object or object life cycle management complexity..etc.

Comment: There's no chance of loosing state. I don't think there are any practical concerns there.